# How can I safely down-convert an integer to a bitfield in the context of bitwise or?

Tags: c++, g++

Earlier, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39880892/391161) and received an answer that worked for the example I provided, but appears to not generalize to bitwise OR. Here is the example from that question, but with bitwise OR added.

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct MaskAndCount{
    uint64_t occupied : 56;
    uint8_t numOccupied : 8;
};

int main(){
    int count = 7;
    MaskAndCount foo;
    foo.occupied &= ~(1L << count) & 0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    foo.occupied |= (1L << count) & 0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
}
```

Now, when we compile, we do not get the warning from the first line, but we do get a warning from the second line.

```
g++ -Wconversion Main.cc
Main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
Main.cc:12:18: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int:56’ from ‘long unsigned int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
     foo.occupied |= (1L << count) & 0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

Again, I will pose the same two questions.

1. Will the conversion as written have the desired effect of truncating the higher bits of the value on the right?
2. Is there is a way to either silence the warning locally or expressing the same behavior with a different syntax which does not trigger the warning?

Comment: Good guy. Leading their own dupe finding.

Comment: You flagged your own question for closing? I don't think I've ever seen that before.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've seen that a number of times before, and done myself.